# format date using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, date, date-parsing

I am getting parser Exception while parsing the below date using simple date format API.

```
  String inputTimeStamp = "2012/07/19 09:49:00 - GMT -08:00";
  java.text.SimpleDateFormat dateformate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  effDate = dateformate.parse(inputTimeStamp);
```

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat dateformate=
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

to

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat dateformate=
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

You have slashes (/) in your inputTimeStamp

Comment: Your time zone is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are parsing a date which is in a different format then you have described it to the `SimpleDateFormat`. If `effDate` is of type `String` and should hold the formatted date, the following code might solve it, although there is not supposed to be an space between `GMT`and `-08:00` .

```
 String inputTimeStamp = "2012/07/19 09:49:00 - GMT -08:00";
 SimpleDateFormat inputDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss - z"); 
 SimpleDateFormat dateformate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 effDate = dateformate.format(inputDateFormat.parse(inputTimeStamp));
```

I would highly recommend also [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net), especially when you want to do calculations on the date.

```
 String inputTimeStamp = "2012/07/19 09:49:00 - GMT -08:00";
 DateTimeFormatter inputDateformat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss - z Z"); 
 DateTimeFormatter dateformate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 effDate = dateformate.print(inputDateFormat.parseDateTime(inputTimeStamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern would be: `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss - z` where z is for General Time Zone. [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss - z");
```

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) FYR